# Re: Cisco Networking fiber to fiber

Tags: discussion, questions

I understand that questions shouldn't be cross-posted, but clearly [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6098/cisco-networking-fiber-to-fiber) belongs here and not on Server Fault

Comment: If a question is sitting idle (without useful answers), and you think it's a good fit here, it might be a candidate for migration.

Comment: Perhaps you could quote the OP portions that are in question; the link is now dead.

Comment: @Fizzle I think there's nothing left to discuss, do you?

Comment: @Ron I have no idea. Now that the post in question has been removed, I don't know any context.

Answer (score 2):

> Ron said:
>   ... clearly this question belongs here and not on Server Fault

I'm sorry, but you're mistaken.  Quoting Server Fault's [What is on-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic):

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> Server Fault is a site for system and network administrators needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity.
>
> If your question is about…
>
> - Network routing, switches, and firewalls

We have significant overlap with Server Fault.  It's part of Stack Exchange... we're a focused group of network engineers with no other "noise".  They have network engineers mixed in with system administrators and jacks-of-all trades.

Also consider how much overlap there is for linux topics...

- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
- [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)